# Address Validation with ZP4 from semaphore

Tags: node.js, mongodb, street-address

We have an application and we were looking into adding address validation on the data we currently have on the database. Our stack is mainly node.js and MongoDB. I looked for a solution that was cost effective and I came across Semaphore ZP4. But according to their documentation, they offer a DVD with the software that only works on windows and it's run locally on the machine. Does anyone have any experience with it and trying to integrate this with a node.js application and is there another better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Semaphore, but I can tell you that it is a bad idea to use data off of a DVD because validated addresses change all the time. You want up to date data for validating addresses. There are other services that have APIs that you can hit and their data is dynamic. Some of those services include SmartyStreets, MelissaData, and Loqate. I would recommend looking into one of those. Most address verification services will give you some lookups/verifications for free so you can test out which one you like. If you don't have too big of a database, you could potentially validate all of the addresses for free using those lookups.

Answer (score 1):

Semaphore Corporation released new DVD editions every month because they were based on the monthly databases the Postal Service released, so camiblanch's concern really didn't apply.  In any case, Semaphore Corporation converted exclusively to online services last June, and can process about 5,900 records per dollar.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Semaphore ZP4. But in general, there are various companies that can help, the exact solution will depend upon your requirements.

As Camiblanch mentions, there are many cloud services around that provide up-to-date addresses and low overhead for you. The one I help to create for example here: https://www.edq.com/uk/products/address-validation/ - that uses simple json results that can fit into your app easily enough. Sample integrations here: https://github.com/experiandataquality/RealTimeAddress

If you have security / data access limitations which mean that you will never open up your solution to the internet, then On Premise solutions are available - similar to the DVD version you are looking at. We (EDQ) create a variety of different deployments including web servers (using soap) that can work with 1000's of internal users or API's you can directly integrate into your app. Those are not just limited to windows.